# How to force install a demo version of a game you already own on Steam?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to force install a demo version of a game, for which you already have a full version on Steam?

The reason I want to install a demo is that I want to use it for tests. For example, comparing performance with different Vulkan implementations for an AMD GPU. The full game takes up significant space on my SSD, and I do not want to keep it.

When I go to the game page, and press "install demo", the installer still wants to install the full game (you can see it asks where to install and the required size is that of the full version).

Comment: Could you just make another Steam account, used exclusively for this testing?

Comment: I can, but it is a crutch. I would like to avoid switching accounts.

Comment: Sometimes the developer may offer the demo version under "Betas" in the game properties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a solution without creating second account.

### Step 1 - find out the appid of the demo version

Demo appid is not the same as full game appid. Visit https://steamdb.info, search your game of interest. In this example I will use FROGUE game, because its demo is just 72 MiB. In search field enter FROGUE, but do not click on the suggested result (it will bring to full version). Just hit enter for your search string. It will bring you to the [results page](https://steamdb.info/search/?a=app&q=frogue). You will see two results: one with app type Game (appid 1936990) and another with app type Demo (appid 1941560). You need the demo (1941560).

### Step 2 - Run the installation command

Launch steam with console tab enabled:

```
$ steam-native -console
```

You can also enable console even if you launched steam without it. For this, run the following command in terminal:

```
$ steam steam://open/console
```

Go to Console tab.
Enter the `app_install <appid>` command, for example:

```
app_install 1941560
```

You will see that downloading started, and then the FROGUE Demo appeared in your library.

Alternatively, use the following command:

```
open steam://install/1941560
```

It will open a usual installation window, showing you the required disk space and the possibility to choose library folder from dropdown list.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for me. Could it be it depends on the demo?

Comment: What did not work? Maybe it depends. Also maybe depends on region. I am from Russia and that frogue demo installed for me. Also worked with Detroit Become Human. Try it. Its appid is [1224230](https://steamdb.info/search/?a=app&q=detroit&type=3&category=0#:~:text=Last%20Update-,1224230,-Demo)

Comment: I tried it with the Salt demo (ID 327870) since I have the full game and it's relatively small. Thanks, I'll try it out later. I might have another possible solution.

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me, but not from the first try. I entered "app_install 327870", nothing happened, nor even any error message in console. Then I searched salt in the store tab, saw there download demo button, pressed it. But did not installed it. Then went back to console tab and executed "app_install 327870" again. This time it worked. So I do not know, maybe it requires you to visit the game store page first?

Comment: I think I did, as I looked at the appID there first. Hmm, strange. I'll try it again. Thank you for your update.

Comment: for me it worked fine (steam deck stable at the end of Nov 2022) however it didnt show any prompts and just went on to install the game's demo.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround solution I found for now is to create a second steam account and install the demo using it.

But would be glad to hear if there are other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this at this exact moment, but apparently **you can**:

> Just go to your web browser [while] logged out and click on 'Download demo'. It will ask you to open Steam and it will download.

Solution found [here](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/558749191319669727/). It's still a nuisance, but less so than using an alternative account.

---

**Updates as I try some options:**

I think the first prerequisite is that you have the full version uninstalled.

Comment: I saw that before creating question here. I tried it, and it does not work for me. Even when you are logged out (from incognito), when you click install, it opens your steam client, in which you are logged in. And it still wants to install a full version of a game. And I do not see if there is a button to force install demo.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I do not have a full version installed and the behavior it such as described. Also I remember when I bought the full game, I had the demo installed. And it just disappeared from the library list, and the full title (without "Demo") appeared there.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer condenses Ashark's great answer into something targetted to devs.*

### If you're developing a demo

To run an unreleased demo you need to have a dev account with sufficient permissions. However, even with those permissions, the demo doesn't show up by default. You need to use something like Ashark's method.

Figure out your appid and use it below instead of DEMO_APPID. This will be **different** from your main game and you can find it on the [partner site](https://partner.steamgames.com/dashboard) next to the name of the demo.

Paste these instructions into Slack/Discord to share with your team (message yourself with them and test they work first!):

1. Click steam://open/console
2. That should open the Console tab in Steam. In there, run: `app_install DEMO_APPID`
3. You should now see the demo in Steam's Downloads. If you got a permissions error, you need our Steamworks admin to add permissions to your account.

Comment: Why the "if you're developing a demo" and "to run an unreleased demo"? Neither things are mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @Joachim: Because I had slightly different constraints and I'm discouraged by my slightly similar questions getting closed as duplicates. But [I'll try posing it as another question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208786/how-to-install-a-steam-demo-youre-developing) and see if it survives.